# Create Subpath Indexes

Tags: basex

I am storing a vast amount of mathematical formulas as Content MathML in BaseX databases. Since a lot of subpaths are similar and repeated it would be nice to have (self-defined) indexes which index not only one element node but subpaths in order to speedup lookup.

E.g. index not only elements which are accessible via

```
//apply
```

but whole (sub)paths like

```
//apply/plus
```

or

```
//apply/plus/ci
```

Is there any way to create such an index? I could not find a way in the documentation.

Comment: Looking at the basex wiki I can see some information in this page about indexing: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes. Maybe Path index is what you are looking for?

Comment: The path index indexes only one element at a time and not multiple elements at a time as I would like to do. The page does not provide any information on the limits of the path index or how to create such an index containing multiple elements in its lookup table or whether it is even possible.